# Fit vertical text into table cell

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, vertical, cell

I am making a relatively simple table in LaTeX however, I came across a problem. I am trying to make the following table:
[image]

However, I get the following:

[image]

My MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,multirow}
\setbox0\hbox{\tabular{@{}l}Hydrocarbons\endtabular}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{System} & K-Model & H-Model \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\rlap{\usebox0}}} \\ 
& Ordinary & SRK &SRK  \\ \cline{2-4}
& Cryogenics & PR & PR \\ \cline{2-4}
& Crude & CS, GS & LK \\ \cline{2-4}
& Vacuum Crude & ESSO & LK\\ \hline
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Power combustion} & SRK &SRK \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Acid, Bases, Electrolytes} & Electrolytes Models &SRK, 
HTSL\\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Chemicals} & Activity Coeff. & Latent Heat\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}​
```

Comment: I increased the height of the cells a little, is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kxk4g.png) good?

Comment: Yes, it is!! how did you do it?

Comment: I posted an answer with the code and explanation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed a few things:

- I changed the `\box0` to a `\newbox\dontdoitbox`. If you use box registers directly you may overwrite things you shouldn't overwrite. I put an automatic register instead (But still there's no point in using a box here...).
- I removed the `\rlap` from the `\usebox`. The `\rlap` makes the box start at the center of the cell, instead of the bottom.
- I included the `array` package and put `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{6pt}` to increase the height of the cells of the table to make everything fit.

Here's the result:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\setbox0\hbox{\tabular{@{}l}Hydrocarbons\endtabular}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{6pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{System} & K-Model & H-Model \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\usebox0}}
& Ordinary & SRK &SRK  \\ \cline{2-4}
& Cryogenics & PR & PR \\ \cline{2-4}
& Crude & CS, GS & LK \\ \cline{2-4}
& Vacuum Crude & ESSO & LK\\ \hline
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Power combustion} & SRK &SRK \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Acid, Bases, Electrolytes} & Electrolytes Models &SRK, 
HTSL\\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Chemicals} & Activity Coeff. & Latent Heat\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

an alternative with use of packages `makecell` and `rotating`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell,multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\makegapedcells
\settowidth\rotheadsize{Hydrocarbons}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{System}
                    & K-Model   & H-Model       \\\hline
    & Ordinary      & SRK       & SRK           \\ \cline{2-4}
    & Cryogenics    & PR        & PR            \\ \cline{2-4}
    & Crude         & CS, GS    & LK            \\ \cline{2-4}
\multirow[t]{-4}{*}{\rothead{Hydrocarbons}}
    & Vacuum Crude  & ESSO      & LK            \\ \hline
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Power combustion}
                    & SRK       & SRK           \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Acid, Bases, Electrolytes}
                    & Electrolytes Models
                                & SRK, HTSL     \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Chemicals}
                    & Activity Coeff.
                                & Latent Heat   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}​
```

[image]

Comment: You are very talented with LaTeX. I vote all +1.